# Sed, awk or perl to filter incomplete data column

Tags: regex, linux, perl, awk, sed

New to natural language processing. I have csv file containing about one million rows. I want to filter-out the third row that do not contain any data. For example

```
user1,user2, it really is  
user3,user4, oh nothin  
user5,user9, 
user7,user8,  
user9,user10,  
user11,user12, i know im in 
user13,user14, 
user15,user16, 
user17,user18, i think that might     
user19,user20, what u 
user21,user22, hmmm you never know 
user23,user24, nicee
```

**Expected output**

```
user1,user2, it really is 
user3,user4, oh nothin   
user11,user12, i know im in  
user17,user18, i think that might     
user19,user20, what u  
user21,user22, hmmm you never know  
user23,user24, nicee
```

I have tried

```
awk -F',+' 'NF == 3' file > file
```

However, does not work

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by *"natural language processing"*. Do the records in your file all have three columns, with the third sometimes empty? So there are always two commas in every line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '$NF!=""' file
user1,user2, it really is
user3,user4, oh nothin
user11,user12, i know im in
user17,user18, i think that might
user19,user20, what u
user21,user22, hmmm you never know
user23,user24, nicee
```

`'$NF'!=""` is actually a condition that checks whether 3rd field is populated.

**PS:** You cannot really do:

```
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '$NF!=""' file > file
```

**As input file and redirected file are same and you will end up with 0 byte file.**

Better you do:

```
awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '$NF!=""' file > file.out && mv file.out file
```

Comment: That will fail if $NF is non-empty but evaluates to numeric zero. Also your FS value REQUIRES at least 1 space after the comma and it's not clear that there always will be. With the given data and your FS setting $NF is the 2nd field, not the 3rd.

Comment: Yes that's right I shouldn't have used `*` instead of `+`

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, this prints a line unless it ends with a comma and whitespace.

```
perl -ne'/,\s*$/ or print' file
```

**output**

```
user1,user2, it really is
user3,user4, oh nothin
user11,user12, i know im in
user17,user18, i think that might
user19,user20, what u
user21,user22, hmmm you never know
user23,user24, nicee
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if you're against using vim or not but, you can load your file in vim, and do:

```
:g/,\s\+$/d
```

:g is vim's global (operate on the entire file)

Syntax is :g/pattern/command

What is between the forward slashes is the regex pattern.  Here we look for a comma, followed by as much whitespace as we can find (\s+) until we hit the end of the line ($).

The command 'd' means "delete the line" when the regex matches.

Finally:

```
:wq
```

Writes the file (w) and quits (q).

Answer (score 1):

Every line of your input has 3 fields (since there's always 2 commas) so NF is always 3. You want to test the contents of $NF being null, not the value of NF being 3. Also, NEVER do `cmd file > file` for any command as the shell could do the `> file` part before the `cmd file` part and so zap your input file before it's been read by `cmd`.

You need:

```
awk -F', *' '$NF!=""' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

This problem/example has absolutely nothing to do with natural language processing, btw.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so elegant, but perhaps more clear and easier to modify the field number:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open IN,$ARGV[0];
while(<IN>){
    @line = split(",",$_);
    if($line[2] =~ /\S/){
        print;
    }
}
```

$ARGV[0] is the name of the file whit your table; \S means any character (not blank) at field #2 (fields are numbered from 0).

Comment: Could you provide some explanation?  You can edit your answer to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Perl` answer which I purposefully chose to demonstrate the usage of the `-a` autosplit and the `-F` field delimiter options:

```
perl -anF, -e 'print if $F[2] =~ /\S/' file > file.out
```

But I would probably prefer `grep` in this particular case:

```
grep -E -v ',\s*$' file > file.out
```